# I cannot bootstrap the Spork configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, installation, spork

I run `spork --bootstrap` on the command line and I get the error `-bash: spork: command not found`

I know I have spork installed because when I run `bundle show spork` I get `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc3`

I even tried changing the directory to where Spork is and ran `spork --bootstrap` but I get the same error message.

What should I do?

Comment: What is the output of `which spork`?

Comment: There is no output of `which spork`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it sounds like you used Bundler to install it, try running `bundle exec spork --bootstrap` and it should work.